# Generating a sequence of leap years using clpfd

Tags: prolog, clpfd

The code below checks whether a given year is a leap year or not. The arithmetic is formulated using declarative integer arithmetic from the library [clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd), in order that the query can be run in 'reverse' to generate a sequence of leap years. There are two variants of the code, altering the test for whether the year is a century or not, but the behaviour of each variant differs and neither of them work correctly.

I want to generate a sequence of leap years from 1990 to 2005. To do this, I am entering the query `Year in 1990..2005,leap_year1(Year),indomain(Year).` (or `leap_year2` to test the second variant).

The code that I've written is (using SWI-Prolog 8.0.2):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

leap_year1(Year) :-
  Year #> 0,
  Year mod 4 #= 0,
  (
    Year mod 100 #= 0 ->
      Year mod 400 #= 0      % 2000 is a leap year, 1900 is not
    ;
      true                   % Not a century
  ).

leap_year2(Year) :-
  Year #> 0,
  Year mod 4 #= 0,
  (
    Year mod 100 #\= 0 ->
      true                   % Not a century
    ;
      Year mod 400 #= 0      % 2000 is a leap year, 1900 is not
  ).
```

The results of the queries are (SWI-Prolog 8.0.2):

```
?- Year in 1990..2005,leap_year1(Year),indomain(Year).
Year = 2000.

?- Year in 1990..2005,leap_year2(Year),indomain(Year).
Year = 1992 ;
Year = 1996 ;
Year = 2004.
```

As you can see, neither query correctly generates the full sequence of leap years (1992, 1996, 2000, 2004).

Further, the following queries around the year 1900 also generate anomalous results (comments added):

```
% Verify that 1900 is not a leap year
?- not(leap_year1(1900)), not(leap_year2(1900)).
true.

% Verify that 1892, 1896, 1904 are leap years
?- leap_year1(1892), leap_year1(1896), leap_year1(1904).
true.

?- leap_year2(1892), leap_year2(1896), leap_year2(1904).
true.

% No solutions found (!)
?- Year in 1890..1905,leap_year1(Year),indomain(Year).
false.

% Solutions found as expected (complete result)
?- Year in 1890..1905,leap_year2(Year),indomain(Year).
Year = 1892 ;
Year = 1896 ;
Year = 1904.
```

Is there an explanation for this behaviour? How should I modify `leap_year()` so that it generates a complete sequence?

**Update:** *(more?) complete, but don't understand why (!)*

Splitting out the check for centuries improves the completeness of the query:

```
leap_year_century_fix(Year) :-
  Year mod 100 #\= 0.

leap_year_century_fix(Year) :-
  Year mod 100 #= 0,
  Year mod 400 #= 0.      % 2000 is a leap year, 1900 is not

leap_year3(Year) :-
  Year #> 0,
  Year mod 4 #= 0,
  leap_year_century_fix(Year).
```

Now:

```
?- Year in 1890..1905,leap_year3(Year),indomain(Year).
Year = 1892 ;
Year = 1896 ;
Year = 1904 ;
false.

?- Year in 1990..2015,leap_year3(Year),indomain(Year).
Year = 1992 ;
Year = 1996 ;
Year = 2004 ;
Year = 2008 ;
Year = 2012 ;
Year = 2000.
```

Comment: Do not mix `->` and constraints. Rather use disjunction directly with "guards" for both case. Even better, user [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+if_)

Answer (score 4):

Express it simply using **and** and **or**, and use *reification* for the **or**:

```
leap(Y) :-
    Y #> 0,
    Y mod 4 #= 0,
    (Y mod 100 #\= 0) #\/ (Y mod 400 #= 0).
```